# How to load xib file for cell in tableview in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I saw there are lots of resources available on net regarding this question. I have to load a different XIB (`UIViewContoller`) file for my cell. I have designed my cell looks there and I want to load that design in my cell.

I wrote this code but I am getting an exception.

```
-[UIView setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6040de0
2011-07-11 14:42:27.461 TableViewTest[2776:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setTableViewStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6040de0'
```

And here is my code of loading nib file

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
    // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"loadXibfile" owner:self options:nil];
    // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}


return cell;
```

Comment: http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/  This is good tutorial for this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `UITableViewCell` and not `UIView` in your XIB file.

Comment: +1 Helped me. why this people don't accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution and it is useful for me and home for you or some else may be.

```
 cell = [[[YourCustomcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
        NSArray *toplavelobject=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"YourCustomcell" owner:self options:nil];
        for(id c in toplavelobject)
        {
            if ([c isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell=(YourCustomcell *) c;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Though not a direct answer to your issue, I recommend you make use of this UITableViewCellFactory class, it's very convenient:

http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/07/16/loading-uitableviewcells-from-a-nib-file/

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d",indexPath.row];
    LatestNewsCell  *cell = (LatestNewsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LatestNewsCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. Again some of the technique is quite awkward and I need improvement.

First I created a new subclass of UITableViewCell. The problem is I do not get an option to check "include" xib. It's as if xib is meant only for UIViewcontroller. I suppose you can create a subclass of UIViewController with XIB and then crate another subclass of UITableViewCell and move the template to your subclass of UIViewController.

Works.

Then I put these function:

```
@implementation BGCRBusinessForDisplay2

- (NSString *) reuseIdentifier {
    return [[self class] reuseIdentifier];
};
+ (NSString *) reuseIdentifier {
    return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
};
```

To initialize I do:

```
- (BGCRBusinessForDisplay2 *) initWithBiz: (Business *) biz
{
    if (self.biz == nil) //First time set up
    {
        self = [super init]; //If use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier then I shouldn't change the address self points to right
        NSString * className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
        PO (className);
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:self.view]; //What is this for? self.view is of type BGCRBusinessForDisplay2. That view should be self, not one of it's subview Things don't work without it though
    }
    if (biz==nil)
    {
        return self; //Useful if we only want to know the height of the cell
    }

    self.biz = biz;
    self.Title.text = biz.Title; //Let's set this one thing first
    self.Address.text=biz.ShortenedAddress;
```

The  `[self addSubview:self.view];`  is kind of awkward. It's what other says I should do and it won't work without it. Actually I want self.view to be self, rather than a subView of self. But hei.... Don't know how to do it otherwise.
...

Then I implement this for cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //[FetchClass singleton].FetchController
    if([BGMDCRFetchClass singleton].FetchController.fetchedObjects.count!=0){

        BGCRBusinessForDisplay2 *cell = (BGCRBusinessForDisplay2*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[BGCRBusinessForDisplay2 reuseIdentifier]];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell =[BGCRBusinessForDisplay2 alloc];
        }
        else{
            while (false);
        }

        Business * theBiz=[[BGMDCRFetchClass singleton].FetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell = [cell initWithBiz:theBiz];

        return cell;
        //return theBiz.CustomCell;
    }else{
        UITableViewCell * tvc=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"tvc"];
        return tvc;
    }
}
```

Notice that I separate alloc from init. That's kind of awkward. That is why in my     - `(BGCRBusinessForDisplay2 *) initWithBiz: (Business *) biz` if a cell has been initialized before, I simply don't do the upper part of the init. I simply assign values of Business * to the various outlet in the BGCRBusinessForDisplay2.

I someone can improve my answers they are welcome. So far it works.